# How to set a crontab job for a perl script

Tags: perl, cron

I have a Perl script which I want to run every 4 hours through cron. But somehow it fails to execute through cron and runs fine if I run it through command line. Following is the command which I set in crontab:

```
perl -q /path_to_script/script.pl > /dev/null
```

Also, when I run this command on command prompt, it does not execute but when I go in the leaf folder in `path_to_script` and execute the file, it runs fine.

Also, where will the log files of this cron job be created so that I can view them?

Comment: I assume that you have the cron time fields setup properly, and that you left them out on purpose? I.e. you DO know that you have to write like this "* */4 * * * command" in your crontab file -- right?

Comment: You may have PATH environment variable not configured in your crontab. Put full path to perl executable in your string and see if it helps

Comment: What is `perl -q` supposed to do? I get the error `Unrecognized switch: -q`

Comment: When you're debugging your cron script, don't send its possibly helpful output to /dev/null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should probably change the working directory to "leaf folder".

Try this in your crontab command:

```
cd /path_to_script; perl script.pl >/dev/null
```

Wrt. log files. Cron will mail you the output. But since you sent stdout to /dev/null, only stderr will be mailed to you.

If you want the output saved in a log file, then pipe the stderr/stdout output of the script into a file, like so:

```
cd /path_to_script; perl script.pl 2>&1 >my_log_file
```

Comment: Thanx :) Could you please help me out with another issue -- I want to send an email through a perl script - not using CGI module or Mod_Perl but through a simple perl script. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I can't answer that off hand in a comment. I'm sure a Google search will result in lots of examples of doing just that.

Comment: There are answers to the email question already on Stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 2):

Usually *cron* will send you mail with the output of your program. When you're figuring it out, you probably want to check the environment. It won't necessarily be the same environment as your login shell (since it's not a login shell):

```
 foreach my $key ( keys %ENV ) {
     printf "$key: $$ENV{$key}\n";
     }
```

If you're missing something you need, set it in your crontab:

```
 SOME_VAR=some_value
 HOME=/Users/Buster
```

If you need to start in a particular directory, you should [chdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) there. The starting directory from a cron job probably isn't what you think it is. Without an argument, [chdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) changes to your home directory. However, sometimes those environment variables might not be set in your cron session, so it's probably better to have a default value:

```
 chdir( $ENV{HOME} || '/Users/Buster' );
```

At various critical points, you should give error output. This is a good thing even in non-*cron* programs:

```
 open my $fh, '<', $some_file or die "Didn't find the file I was expecting: $!";
```

If you redirect things to */dev/null*, you lose all that information that might help you solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

looks like you may have missed the

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

at the start of your perl script which is why you might need perl -q to run it
once you have added that line you can run it directly from the command line using

```
/path_to_script/script.pl
```

Comment: If you use `perl` on the command line, you don't need the shebang line.

Comment: true, or if you put the shebang in there you don't need perl -q :) and then you don't have to keep writing it every time you call the script. Plus the script call final destination is cron not the command line, where of course you could write perl -q once more if you wish. semantics r us. :)

Comment: You never need the -q. It's not a perl switch.

Comment: you are so right -q is not a perl switch, my folly to copy the OP sample.

Answer (score -3):

If you use a command in your perl program, i advise you to put the full path to the command in your program.

I have try to load environment but it is not more helpful.

After a oversee with one colleague, i think it's from interaction between perl and the system environment.

Best regards,
Moustapha Kourouma